# What is "provider name" in google cloud and how it is raleted to google cloud projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wanted to go to https://console.cloud.google.com
[image]

But i typed just https://console.cloud.google without "com" and this page opened.
[image]

What's asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the term "provider name" refers to the name of the cloud service provider that you are using. It is an essential component in the configuration of your Google Cloud projects. The provider name is used to identify the specific cloud service provider and its associated services that you want to utilize within your project.

When creating a Google Cloud project, you have the option to choose from various cloud service providers, such as Google Cloud Platform (GCP), Amazon Web Services (AWS), or Microsoft Azure. Each provider offers a unique set of services and features.

The provider name is specified in the project configuration files, such as the provider section in a serverless.yml file for a serverless application. It helps to define the target cloud provider for deploying and managing your application.

For example, if you are using Google Cloud Platform as your provider, the provider name would be set as google in the project configuration. This ensures that the project is associated with the Google Cloud Platform and its services.

By specifying the provider name, you can easily switch between different cloud service providers or manage multiple projects with different providers within your Google Cloud environment.
for example it could be any of the following example .

1. Amazon Web Service (AWS)
2. ServerSpace
3. Microsoft Azure
4. Google Cloud Platform
5. IBM Cloud Services
6. Adobe Creative Cloud
7. Kamatera
8. VMware
9. Rackspace
10. Red Hat
11. Salesforce
12. Oracle Cloud
13. SAP
14. Verizon Cloud
15. Navisite
16. Dropbox

in conclude :
the provider name in Google Cloud is the identifier for the cloud service provider you are using within your project, and it plays a crucial role in configuring and managing your Google Cloud projects.
to get or set your sso you may use this link to help https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/topic/7558768?hl=en&ref_topic=7558174

Answer (score 1):

This is for [Sign in a user with an email by using Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/sign-in-user-email)